# Main display randomly turns black and turns back on after some seconds

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Nearly 2 times a day, my main screen randomly turns off (it seems like it is not recognized for a short period of time) and all my open windows will be moved to the second monitor. After 10-60,seconds the main-monitor turns on again, and I can continue to use the OS normally. In the following I have attached the syslog, which was output when the event was happening.

I am using a 144hz monitor (turns off) over DP and a 60hz monitor over HDMI. I am using a RTX 2070 Super with the driver "NVIDIA Server Driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-460-server (proprietary)". I am still verny new to Linux, so tell me if I forgot to add any important files. Thanks!

```
Jun 20 22:10:07 marten-ubuntu rtkit-daemon[1168]: Supervising 7 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jun 20 22:10:29 marten-ubuntu rtkit-daemon[1168]: message repeated 7 times: [ Supervising 7 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.]
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:04 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): connected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): connected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Object .Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_dash_DashToDock_MyDash (0x55d1afb02f10), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: == Stack trace for context 0x55d1a6fd58c0 ==
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: #0   7ffd8595cef0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/GObject.js:571 (37ab14bb6c40 @ 25)
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: #1   55d1adc0dae8 i   /home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/utils.js:104 (f4b5f9a41f0 @ 17)
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: #2   55d1adc0da40 i   /home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/utils.js:52 (f4b5f9a2f88 @ 81)
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: #3   55d1adc0d978 i   /home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/docking.js:1851 (f4b5f9a2358 @ 133)
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: #4   55d1adc0d8e8 i   /home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/docking.js:1673 (f4b5f9a0da8 @ 23)
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: JS ERROR: Error: Argument 'instance' (type interface) may not be null#012_init/GObject.Object.prototype.disconnect@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/GObject.js:571:24#012_remove@/home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/utils.js:104:18#012removeWithLabel@/home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/utils.js:52:22#012_restoreDash@/home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/docking.js:1851:30#012_toggle/this._toggleLater<@/home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/docking.js:1673:18
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Jun 20 22:11:05 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C24FG7x (DFP-3): connected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C24FG7x (DFP-3): Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C24FG7x (DFP-3): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): connected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C24FG7x (DFP-3): connected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C24FG7x (DFP-3): Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C24FG7x (DFP-3): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DP-2: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +1920+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}"
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu rtkit-daemon[1168]: Supervising 6 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu rtkit-daemon[1168]: Successfully made thread 63821 of process 1155 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu rtkit-daemon[1168]: Supervising 7 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): connected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer K242HQL (DFP-2): 600.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C24FG7x (DFP-3): connected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C24FG7x (DFP-3): Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Samsung C24FG7x (DFP-3): 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal DisplayPort
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 2660.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: disconnected
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: Internal TMDS
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-6: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
Jun 20 22:11:07 marten-ubuntu colord[1764]: failed to get session [pid 1602]: No data available
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Object .Gjs_ubuntu-dock_ubuntu_com_dash_DashToDock_MyDash (0x55d1afb02f10), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: == Stack trace for context 0x55d1a6fd58c0 ==
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: #0   7ffd8595cef0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/GObject.js:571 (37ab14bb6c40 @ 25)
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: #1   55d1adc0dae8 i   /home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/utils.js:104 (f4b5f9a41f0 @ 17)
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: #2   55d1adc0da40 i   /home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/utils.js:52 (f4b5f9a2f88 @ 81)
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: #3   55d1adc0d978 i   /home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/docking.js:1851 (f4b5f9a2358 @ 133)
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: #4   55d1adc0d8e8 i   /home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/docking.js:1673 (f4b5f9a0da8 @ 23)
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: JS ERROR: Error: Argument 'instance' (type interface) may not be null#012_init/GObject.Object.prototype.disconnect@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/GObject.js:571:24#012_remove@/home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/utils.js:104:18#012removeWithLabel@/home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/utils.js:52:22#012_restoreDash@/home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/docking.js:1851:30#012_toggle/this._toggleLater<@/home/matrix/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com/docking.js:1673:18
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Jun 20 22:11:08 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Jun 20 22:11:09 marten-ubuntu gnome-shell[1492]: JS ERROR: TypeError: this._workspacesViews[i] is undefined#012_updateWorkspacesFullGeometry@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:756:13#012setWorkspacesFullGeometry@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:746:14#012setWorkspacesFullGeometry@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/viewSelector.js:301:33#012_updateWorkspacesGeometry@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overviewControls.js:498:27#012vfunc_allocate@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overviewControls.js:402:14#012_computeWindowCenter@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:302:35#012_init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:160:14#012_addWindowClone@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1856:21#012_init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspace.js:1174:22#012_init@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:348:27#012_updateWorkspacesViews@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:680:24#012show@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspacesView.js:612:14#012show@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/viewSelector.js:276:33#012_animateVisible@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:580:27#012show@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:566:14#012toggle@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:689:18#012_initializeUI/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:223:22
Jun 20 22:11:14 marten-ubuntu systemd[1125]: Started snap.code.code.24294404-581a-402f-a88b-927d5768461e.scope.
Jun 20 22:11:14 marten-ubuntu systemd[1125]: snap.code.code.24294404-581a-402f-a88b-927d5768461e.scope: Succeeded.
Jun 20 22:11:17 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (EE) client bug: timer event2 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-10ms), your system is too slow
Jun 20 22:11:23 marten-ubuntu /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1167]: (EE) client bug: timer event2 debounce short: scheduled expiry is in the past (-2ms), your system is too slow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My power adapter was broken. Should've checked before...